# Phmagic draw text on image using sql

Tags: php, sql, image, text, dynamic

Is there a way to do this: http://www.francodacosta.com/phmagick/examples/drawingte
But on top of an image instead of just using a background color? Also, is there a way to make it draw the text from an SQL database instead of just imputing the text manually? Any help is much appreciated. Thanks! :-)

Comment: Have you read all the [documentation for phMagick](http://www.francodacosta.com/phmagick/examples)? You can do that by creating an image using the text examples you use above, and then using the [watermark](http://www.francodacosta.com/phmagick/examples/watermarks) function to overlay it.  It's a lot simpler to do it without the phMagick wrapper if you ask me, just use ImageMagick directly.